# Importing data using temp tables in Power BI

Tags: sql, postgresql, powerbi

I have the following SQL query I want to use to import data into Power BI. It involves the creation of a temp table and using that table as the main data source. How can I do this in Power BI? I tried using this query in the editor when loading data from a database, but I keep getting an error like so
[image]

I basically used this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/kyanyoga/sample-sales-data and loaded it into a postgressql database.

```
-- 1. Create temp table to house temporary results
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_quantity;
CREATE TEMP TABLE product_quantity
 (product_line varchar, this_month_quantity integer, last_month_quantity integer)

 --2. Quantity ordered for each Product line for current month is inserted into temporary table.
INSERT INTO product_quantity (product_line, this_month_quantity, last_month_quantity)
SELECT "productline", SUM("quantityordered"), 0
FROM test_schema.sales_data_sample
where "month_id" = 3 and "year_id" = 2003
GROUP BY "productline";

--3. Quantity ordered for each Product line for last month is inserted into temporary table.
INSERT INTO product_quantity (product_line, this_month_quantity, last_month_quantity)
SELECT "productline", 0, SUM("quantityordered")
FROM test_schema.sales_data_sample
where "month_id" = 2 and "year_id" = 2003
GROUP BY "productline";

--4. Retrieve required results.
select
    "product_line",
    sum("this_month_quantity") as "this_month_quantity",
    sum("last_month_quantity") as "last_month_quantity"
FROM product_quantity
group by "product_line"
```

Comment: Does the table actually have to be TEMP? (if that is the issue). Also, you could try disabling folding as per the message

Comment: Preferably. Is it not possible? Do you know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: My guess is that the query is too complex to apply "folding". Take a look at this post about disabling folding and see if it helps: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Query-Folding-disable/td-p/797007

Comment: I actually tried that it didnt work out :(

Comment: Are you saying you set `[EnableFolding=false]` but you still got the same error? Next I suggest you use a normal table not a temp table and see if that helps.

Comment: You could also just convert your SQL into a big inline SQL query without a temp table at all

Answer (score 0):

Does this query run without an error?

I've converted your query to one big inline query.

```
select
    ST."product_line",
    sum(ST."this_month_quantity") as "this_month_quantity",
    sum(ST."last_month_quantity") as "last_month_quantity"
FROM
(
    SELECT "productline", 
    SUM("quantityordered") as this_month_quantity, 
    0 as last_month_quantity
    FROM test_schema.sales_data_sample
    where "month_id" = 3 and "year_id" = 2003
    GROUP BY "productline"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "productline", 
    0, 
    SUM("quantityordered")
    FROM test_schema.sales_data_sample
    where "month_id" = 2 and "year_id" = 2003
    GROUP BY "productline"
) as ST
group by ST."product_line"
```

(note I've just taken a guess at conversion - I don't have a postgresql to test on)